# GWT's built-in XSRF protection

Tags: gwt, csrf

I have a few questions regarding this:

- In general, is XSRF still an issue with up-to-date browsers? To my knowledge cross-domain requests have been disabled by default and are now controlled through CORS. And when people are using outdated browsers, there are probably so many security holes in them that XSRF wouldn't matter anyways. BTW the XsrfTokenServlet class is *still* marked as not-for-production, so the GWT devs seem to consider it not an important issue or don't trust their own implemention.
- Secondly, GWT uses a servlet to create the XSRF token. Doesn't that introduce an obvious attack vector by returning the (hashed) JSESSIONID? I thought you do XSRF exactly because the attacker doesn't know JSESSIONID and simply makes your browser send it along with the request. Now that request returns the critical hash of it that he can use to pretend he knows the JSESSIONID. What do I get wrong here? Shouldn't the JSESSIONID be hashed on the client side independently of the server to prove that the client actually can read the JSESSIONID cookie which isn't possible when calling the site from a page loaded from a different site?

Comment: Not doubting that modern browsers have made attacks more difficult but bugs are bound to be in every browser. As for the 2nd part, if the token is a simple hash with no key or special salt only the server knows, then the client can re-create it if they steal a session id (which is why letting the client do the hashing is a bad idea).

Comment: the client does not need to re-create it. it's sent to the client so the client can identify itself during future requests... http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideSecurityRpcXsrf.html

Comment: Never mentioned that the client needs to recreate it. I just said that if it were possible for the client to recreate it if they just knew the session id then it does defeat its purpose a bit because bugs that leak cookie data from other sites are a prime target for people looking for exploits. The XSRF token itself is never stored anywhere persistently so only if you go to the page legitimately will you read it.

Comment: that's not true. the xsrf token is generated from the jsessionid, so IT IS actually stored as a cookie. you simply apply a md5 sum.